# Run and debug Asp file in notepad++

Tags: debugging, notepad++

I was wondering if there is any way i could run asp files in notepad++ and how to debug them.
Any plugin do I need to add in?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Notepad++ is suited for that, just use Visual Studio and a server.

Comment: You don't need a separate server, Visual Studio comes with a built in web server.  And the Express version of Visual Studio Web Developer is free.

Comment: Thanks you for your advices . I open ASP files with File Menu > Open tag in Visual Studio 2008 but Starting debugging F5 is disable under Debug menu.Any another ways to open? Do i need to connect DB and how to? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem like this is easly possible, but maby you will find some workarounds in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053583/how-to-use-debug-points-in-notepad).